# iPhone webview keyboard push up the layout and leaves it up

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, webview

When editing text fields the native keyboard pops the webview up and leaves it up. just like when you leave the toilet seat up.
How do i revert to the original scroll position after the native keyboard have retracted?
I there an event that can be caught. I'm thinking of an ugly hack, reloading the entire webview after each edit. It seems like the only way to go.

Comment: You compare text fields with a toilet seat? :D

Comment: @Derek : For a real troll that would be a good metaphor actually :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming existence of some library that supports CSS selectors:

```
var positionResetHandler = function () {
  var self = {},
      lastY = null;

  self.inputFieldFocusHandler = function () {
    lastY = window.scrollY;
  };

  self.inputFieldBlurHandler = function () {
    if (lastY) {
      window.scrollTo(0, lastY);
      lastY = null;
    }
  };

  return self;
};

var handler = positionResetHandler();

$("input").bind("focus", handler.inputFieldFocusHandler);
$("input").bind("blur", handler.inputFieldBlurHandler);
```

On focus of any input field then record the y position of the page. On blur of any input field then scroll the page back to the last known y position

Comment: Thanks @sciritai i got your example working after modifying it a few places.

I needed to add parantheses to return the eventhandler
positionResetHandler().inputFieldFocusHandler  
lastY needed a this keyword / specifier.  
Otherwise lastY would be null in the handler functions.  
I don't use jquery, that's why i'm using addEventListener.

Comment: @DevNull - `document.querySelectorAll` is a native function that is basically the jQuery selector.

Comment: I updated my answer to work based on your feedback. 'this' is actually not needed. lastY will be contained in the closure that's formed when inputFieldFocusHandler and inputFieldBlurHandler are respectively interpreted. I used the module pattern rather than prototypical inheritance.